# Implications of using programmatically-generated keys in non-clustered Redis Lua scripts

Tags: redis

The [Redis docs state](https://redis.io/docs/manual/programmability/eval-intro/):

> **Important:** to ensure the correct execution of scripts, both in standalone and clustered deployments, all names of keys that a script accesses must be explicitly provided as input key arguments. The script **should only** access keys whose names are given as input arguments. Scripts **should never** access keys with programmatically-generated names or based on the contents of data structures stored in the database.

This makes sense in a cluster scenario, where the side effects of a script must be known in advance. However, for non-clustered deployments, my understanding of Lua scripts in Redis is that these scripts run atomically, essentially acquiring a global lock of the database.

I have a use case where I need programmatically generated key names: I track a list of items in a set, and for every item in that set, I need to read or update that item's data stored in a separate hash value. Or, in Lua pseudocode:

```lua
local items = redis.call("SMEMBERS", "items")
for _, item in ipairs(items) do
  local item_data = redis.call("HGETALL", "item:"..item)
  -- Use item_data for further processing...
end
```

I cannot easily pre-calculate these key names, because the list of items might change between the fetching of the item list and the invocation of the script.

In such a scenario, is using programmatically generated keys inherently unsound? Or is this use case OK, as long as no clustering is used? What are the implications of not listing keys on script invocation in a standalone Redis setup?

Comment: If you're sure that you never need to migrate your standalone Redis to Redis Cluster, IMHO, it's OK to dynamically generate keys.

Comment: @for_stack I hope that there's a way to confirm that assumption :)

Comment: https://github.com/redis/redis/issues/10296 has a discussion on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the discussion at https://github.com/redis/redis/issues/10296 (thanks @yeniv for the link), this seems to be sound in non-clustered mode, albeit with some caveats.

To summarize from the linked GitHub issue:

1. **In general**, it's a bad idea to dynamically generate scripts with EVAL, where each invocation generates a different script, because it causes the cache to grow a lot.
2. **In cluster mode**, referring to key names that are not mentioned as argument can cause cluster aware clients not to route the script to the right cluster node, or cause redis itself not to reject it with MOVED error.
3. **In cluster mode**, referring to other key names inside the script could cause some commands in the script to fail with `Script attempted to access a non local key in a cluster node`, after some commands already succeeded (breaking atomicity).
4. **When using ACLs**, an ACL  permission check could fail in the middle of a script (because Redis can't check in advance if it doesn't know the keys in advance).

When not dynamically generating scripts (but use `KEYS[]` instead) and not using cluster mode, dynamically generated keys should be safe.